# Is it ok to submit application with following issue?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, app-store, submit, instruments

I have developed application and all is well. As well, I also keep memory foot print very low.No leaks show during application run. I tested application more than two hour and there is no crashing report. But when i checked application on instruments at that time it's show me following leaks.I have checked my app but there is no such leaking object. "**Even I used app continue 12 hour and it didn't crash or stop".**

//Here the screen shot of instruments.

[image]

///>>>>>>Here, I uploaded latest screenshot of leaks.It may help somebody to understand where the leak is.
// I think it's library file leaks(CoreFoundation)...Please Suggest What to do..

[image]

Please  help me, This is really screw me up.

Thanks.

Comment: have you build and analyzed your project?

Comment: @SreeCharan :YES...but i didn't found any thing like leaks.

Comment: In most cases this happens when you don't retain an attribute which is object and send late messages to it in other methods, late.

Comment: @RKK : So, It's an issue or apple will ok with this..if app running very smooth and without any issue like memory usage.

Comment: yes its an issue. no need worry about. just clean and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all of the 'memory leaks', are actual leaks. And some of the reported issues may be caused by Apple libraries themselves. Typically all the singletons, static variables, and some c level variables are 'leaked', but only once and are not considered a threat to memory.

Foundation classes such as NSString, NSArray, etc. are optimized to handle heavy workload. And some objects may be kept in the memory to be reused later. Such as @"".

So unless the issue is accumulating over time, just go for it, submit your app as it is. You still can fix it later, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks man for reply..I am also thinking about it's library issue.Than after i will check it again. But i am happy with your reply(little confirmation)...Will add plus five...

Answer (score 2):

Hey analyze you code using "**command+shift+b**" and fix all leaks whatever coming after analyzing, submit it to app store. I don't think we can fix all leaks shown by instrument, so better to go with **command+shift+b**. I think we should use instrument only when getting memory warning and crashes due to insufficient memory.

Comment: Static analyzer is a very good tool, but it is far from perfect, and will not detect all of the leaks. In fact there is a range of issues, it cannot detect at all. Therefore, Instruments are always of some help. By the way, I tend to have more luck debugging with heap snapshots in Allocation Tool, rather than Memory Leaks, but that may be only me.

Comment: I did analyzing using static analyzer and it shows me only one leaks..That's >>>>>"CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);"<<<<<.But i don't think this is leak.Because if i remove this line than after instruments show me leak and i did static analyze and found no issue or leak...It's make me confuse..I don't know what to do..